# Inversify-props: Ambiguous match found for serviceIdentifier when 'get'ing service in Nuxt plugin

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, inversifyjs

I'm using Typescript Nuxt and inversify-props to implement dependency injection throughout my application. I'm running into an issue where if I try to `get` an injected service in a plugin, an `Ambiguous match found for serviceIdentifier: Symbol...` error gets thrown. As a simple test I've added a `get` call in the plugin that does the container resolution

```
import { Context } from '@nuxt/types'
import { cid, container } from 'inversify-props';
import { containerBuilder } from '~/domains/app.container'

export default ({ app }: Context) => {
    containerBuilder();

    const d = container.get(cid.GetOrderQueryHandler);
    console.log(d);
}
```

`containerBuilder` looks like (simplified):

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { container } from 'inversify-props'
import { Order } from './checkout.models'
import { GetOrderQuery, GetOrderQueryHandler } from './queries/getOrderQuery'
import type { IQueryHandler } from '~/infrastructure/interfaces'

export default () => {
  container.addSingleton<IQueryHandler<GetOrderQuery, Order>>(GetOrderQueryHandler);
}
```

I have no idea why calling `get` would result in an ambiguous match because I'm not redefining any classes

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround, though it is a bit of a hack. In the `containerBuilder` function, I have a guard statement that builds a random service. If it builds, then return, otherwise proceed.

```
export function containerBuilder (): void {
  try {
    container.get(cid.GetOrderQueryHandler);
    return;
  } catch (error) {}

  container.addSingleton<IQueryHandler<GetOrderQuery, Order>>(GetOrderQueryHandler);
}
```